# Good introduction to Subversion for inexperienced users?

Tags: version-control, books, subversion

Can you suggest a good introduction to Subversion for UNIX (or Mac OS X) users?  It can assume familiarity with basic command-line usage, but not any advanced topics (with bash scripting counting as "advanced usage" here...)

*Ideally,* the guide should include:

- a short introduction on what a VCS is for (in general) and to the Subversion model in particular;
- quick-start usage (checkout, update/edit/commit cycle)
- installation instructions; bonus points if it mentions that it's already available for all major OSes out there and leads people to install from package and not compile from source...

Comment: not to be grammar/spelling police, but it's *inexperienced*.

Comment: I also recommend **git** the [progit](http://progit.org/book/) book can be read free online.

Comment: @xenoterracide: thanks, I've corrected the spelling

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've always liked this [subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), which contains a great intro and easy to follow examples. It also has a quickstart guide in the appendix. It's the only documentation I've ever used while I was a subversion user.

Comment: Yeah, this is really important.  The subversion book is the best reference there is, and it's wonderfully well-written, and totally accessible to people who have never heard of VCS before.

Comment: You can get the printed version (or digital download) from the O'Reilly website: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596510336/

Answer (score 0):

The svn book (as others have mentioned) is probably the most comprehensive text.

If you want a quick introduction to the concepts then the second chapter of the TortoiseSVN documentation "[Basic Version-Control Concepts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-basics.html)" is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the books mentioned above, I have found svn help from the command line to be helpful, especially when using commands for the first time.  e.g., svn help commit

I learned SVN basics by watching the command line while making changes using a GUI, like TortoiseSVN, and then moving onto the command line and using the built-in help.